# Java 8 Join Map with Collectors.toMap

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I'm trying to collect in a Map the results from the process a list of objects and that it returns a map. I think that I should do it with a Collectors.toMap but I haven't found the way.

This is the code:

```
public class Car {
    List<VersionCar> versions;
    public List<VersionCar> getVersions() {
        return versions;
      }
    }

public class VersionCar {
  private String wheelsKey;
  private String engineKey;
  public String getWheelsKey() {
     return wheelsKey;
  }
  public String getEngineKey() {
    return engineKey;
  }
}
```

process method:

```
private static Map<String,Set<String>> processObjects(VersionCar version) {
    Map<String,Set<String>> mapItems = new HashMap<>();
    mapItems.put("engine", new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(version.getEngineKey())));
    mapItems.put("wheels", new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(version.getWheelsKey())));
    return mapItems;
}
```

My final code is:

```
Map<String,Set<String>> mapAllItems =
                car.getVersions().stream()
                   .map(versionCar -> processObjects(versionCar))
                   .collect(Collectors.toMap()); // here I don't know like collect the map.
```

My idea is to process the list of versions and in the end get a Map with two items:  wheels and engine but with a set<> with all different items for all versions. Do you have any ideas as can I do that with Collectors.toMap or another option?

Comment: Change `.map(...)` to `.flatMap(versionCar -> processObjects(versionCar).entrySet().stream())`, then use `Collectors.groupingBy(Entry::getKey, ...)`. Needs a bit more, but that should get you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks Andreas, that was a great help to find the way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The operator you want to use in this case is probably "reduce"

```
car.getVersions().stream()
        .map(versionCar -> processObjects(versionCar))
        .reduce((map1, map2) -> {
                    map2.forEach((key, subset) -> map1.get(key).addAll(subset));
                    return map1;
                })
        .orElse(new HashMap<>());
```

The lambda used in "reduce" is a BinaryOperator, that merges 2 maps and return the merged map.

The "orElse" is just here to return something in the case your initial collection (versions) is empty.
From a type point of view it gets rid of the "Optional"

Comment: Seems much cleaner than the selected answer to me!

Comment: Not related particular for the case, but this code will throw NPE when `map1` doesn't contains `key`

Comment: Agreed, but as you mentioned, not possible in this case.

Comment: Just keep in mind that is possible a NPE in map1, I added this **map2.forEach((key, subset) -> {
                                if(map1.get(key) != null) {
                                    map1.get(key).addAll(subset);
                                } else {
                                    map1.put(key,subset);
                                }
                            });** in the case when map2 has more keys than map1

Comment: Actually in your case since the keys are in each map "engine" and "wheels" since they are generated by processObjects, the NPE should not happen. But of course, better be safe than sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Collectors.toMap(keyMapper, valueMapper, mergeFunction)`. Last argument is used to resolve collisions between values associated with the same key.

For example:

```
    Map<String, Set<String>> mapAllItems =
            car.getVersions().stream()
                    .map(versionCar -> processObjects(versionCar))
                    .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue,
                            (firstSet, secondSet) -> {
                                    Set<String> result = new HashSet<>();
                                    result.addAll(firstSet);
                                    result.addAll(secondSet);
                                    return result;
                            }
                    ));
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Vlad, I was looking that.

Comment: You can use a lambda for the binary operator instead of an anonymous inner class, which reads better IMO: `(s1, s2) -> { s1.addAll(s2); return s1; }`. This would require to change your values mapper function to `e -> new HashSet<>(e.getValue())`, in order to not mutate original sets, if this is actually needed at all. Besides, I don't see the need to use `flatMap` here. Just use the maps returned by `processObjects`.

Comment: Sure, I know about lambdas )) but be careful with s1.addAll(...) because you can get immutable set as one of the arguments

Answer (score 0):

To get the `mapAllItems`, we don't need and should not define `processObjects` method:

```
Map<String, Set<String>> mapAllItems = new HashMap<>();
mapAllItems.put("engine", car.getVersions().stream().map(v -> v.getEngineKey()).collect(Collectors.toSet()));
mapAllItems.put("wheels", car.getVersions().stream().map(v -> v.getWheelsKey()).collect(Collectors.toSet()));
```

Or by `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry which is lighter than the Map created by`processObjects`:

```
mapAllItems = car.getVersions().stream()
    .flatMap(v -> Stream.of(new SimpleEntry<>("engine", v.getEngineKey()), new SimpleEntry<>("wheels", v.getWheelsKey())))
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getKey(), Collectors.mapping(e -> e.getValue(), Collectors.toSet())));
```